# pandas sort_values returns incorrectly sorted dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of skills and number of times that skill appears in a person's resume. I'm trying to sort that dataframe by the number of times a skill appears, but when I use pd.sort_values, I get a dataframe that is out of order.

```py
list1 = ['business process improvement', 'usability testing', 'microsoft access', 'pattern recognition']
list2 = [996, 99, 992, 986]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([list1, list2]).T, columns=['skill','total'])

new_df.sort_values(by='total', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

The sorted dataframe I get looks like this:

```py
                          skill total
0  business process improvement   996
2              microsoft access   992
1             usability testing    99
3           pattern recognition   986
```

Obviously the 986 should be above 99, but this is happening all over the dataframe in larger quantities. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: `np.array([list1, list2]).T` creates a NumPy array of strings--that is, *all* the data is converted to strings.  Don't use `np.array` here.

Comment: It's because they are string values. Convert to np.int and then sort

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you mix list1 and list 2 in a numpy array, it changes the data type for the total column to string, which can't be sorted properly. The fix is to convert the total column to int and then sort.

```
(
    new_df.assign(total=new_df.total.astype(int))
    .sort_values(by='total', ascending=False, inplace=False)
)

    skill                           total
0   business process improvement    996
2   microsoft access                992
3   pattern recognition             986
1   usability testing               99
```